# Is there any way to define custom routes in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I want to create a `resources` with adding a couple of custom actions to it, the analogue in rails is:

```
resources :tasks do
  member do
    get :implement
  end
end
```

Which will return me not only 7 standard routes, but 1 new:

```
GET /tasks/:id/implement
```

How can I do it in phoenix?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I want to improve `Dogbert`'s answer a little bit:

```
resources "/tasks", TaskController do
  get "/implement", TaskController, :implement, as: :implement
end
```

The only addition is `as: :implement` in the end of the route.

Thus you will get route named `task_implement_path` instead of ugly `task_task_path`.

Comment: It's a very nice tip indeed.

Comment: How do you describe collection routes?

Comment: I get a `undefined function task_implement_path/1`, any idea?

Comment: Ok my bad, I called it with `task_implement_path(task)` instead of `task_implement_path(conn, :implement, task)`. Not very DRY, though.

Answer (score 18):

You can add a `get` inside the `do` block of `resources`.

#### web/router.ex

```
resources "/tasks", TaskController do
  get "/implement", TaskController, :implement
end
```

`$ mix phoenix.routes`

```
     task_path  GET     /tasks                     MyApp.TaskController :index
     task_path  GET     /tasks/:id/edit            MyApp.TaskController :edit
     task_path  GET     /tasks/new                 MyApp.TaskController :new
     task_path  GET     /tasks/:id                 MyApp.TaskController :show
     task_path  POST    /tasks                     MyApp.TaskController :create
     task_path  PATCH   /tasks/:id                 MyApp.TaskController :update
                PUT     /tasks/:id                 MyApp.TaskController :update
     task_path  DELETE  /tasks/:id                 MyApp.TaskController :delete
task_task_path  GET     /tasks/:task_id/implement  MyApp.TaskController :implement
```

Comment: How can I describe `collection` inside this element?

Comment: Also want to know how you can use this with collection routes under resources.

Comment: get "tasks/implement", Tasks, :implement  # collection route

Comment: How to define something like `GET     /tasks/implement`?

Answer (score 12):

Here is another solution:

```
scope "/tasks" do
  get "/:id/implement", TasksController, :implement
  get "/done", TasksController, :done
end
resources "/tasks", TasksController
```

The `implement` action has a *member* route and the `done` action has a *collection* route.

You can get the path for the former with this function call:

```
tasks_path(@conn, :implement, task)
```

Note that you should place the `resources` line *after* the `scope` block. Otherwise, the Phoenix recognizes `/tasks/done` as the path for `show` action.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a collection route would have to be:

```
get "tasks/implement", Tasks, :implement # collection route
```

I don't think phoenix has member / collection resource routes like rails does.

I found this link were they talk about collection routes a little and give an example like the one I included above:

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/10