# Add a new path inside resources route

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am coming from rails and I'm trying to acheive somthing similar to this in phoenix

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :index] do
  collection do
    post 'claim', to: 'sessions#claim'
  end
end
```

This is the best I could do

```
resources "/session", SessionController, only: [:index, :new]
post "/session/slackLogin", SessionController, :slackLogin
```

I tried adding `collection do end` inside resources "/sessions" but was getting an error. Is there a better way to this?

Comment: Wouldn't `member` create route like `/sessions/:id/claim` here? If so, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267375/is-there-any-way-to-define-custom-routes-in-phoenix/

Comment: @Dogbert edited the question, actually I need a collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question.

```
post "/sessions/slackLogin", SessionController, :slackLogin
resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:index, :new]
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: Except, the `post` route should be moved *before* `resources`, otherwise posting to that route will result in accessing the `update` action with `id` param of `slackLogin`. Otherwise this is the way to go!